# How to See Python Error Messages for Scripts Running on Apache Server?

Tags: python, apache, server, nltk

I have a server side Python script that imports a big package called nltk. It ran at a command prompt, but would not run in Apache server.

I tried the logging and put it as the first import and created a log file immediately after. But nothing is written to the file before the script crashes.

Is there a way to see the "ImportError: no module ..." when the script runs on Apache?

Comment: Did you check in the Apache logs, somewhere in `/var/log` ?

Comment: Thanks, I saw this:  [Thu Aug 09 18:07:50 2018] [error] [client ::1] NotImplementedError: cannot determine number of cpus\r, referer: http://localhost/index.html

Comment: I would like to know how to dump the python error message to browser page (when in apache development environment, obviously not in production) instead of having to go tail the the log file.  Is this possible?  Its worth noting that this is easily configured in PHP.  What about Python?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, there's no built-in way to tell Apache to simply dump error log messages directly to the browser. I'm betting the error_log output happens in an independent part of the Apache pipeline -- just a guess.

Most of the time when someone wants output errors directly to the browser, that person is a developer working in a web script such as PHP, Python, Perl, or other lang. In order to output error messages that occur within your lang interpretter, you have to format the output and pass it through apache as if it was normal output.

**PHP**

Some languages provide an easy way to do this, such as the well known error_reporting switch in PHP.

**Python**

Unfortunately some languages, make this painful or almost impossible and Python is one of them.

At one time this was apparently possible using https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgitb.html

However that library has been deprecated. Seems like the Python community doesn't have much love for developers who want to get immediate feedback about errors in the browser. :(